# how to get list of Databases "Schema" names of MySql using java JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, database, list, jdbc

how to get list of Databases "Schema" names of MySql using java JDBC ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `getSchemas()` method of the DatabaseMetaData is the obvious but with MySQL you have to use `getCatalogs()`

[http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getSchemas()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getSchemas%28%29)
[http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getCatalogs()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getCatalogs%28%29)

Example:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

// change user and password as you need it
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (connectionURL, "user", "password");

ResultSet rs = con.getMetaData().getCatalogs();

while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("TABLE_CAT = " + rs.getString("TABLE_CAT") );
}
```

Comment: JDBC allows to access Schemas and Catalogs but it's meaning is a bit DBMS specific and some provide both while others just one and not always with the method you'd first suspect...

Comment: If the MySQL server is running on Windows, this code prints the database names in lowercase. This may or may not be what you want...

Comment: on the side, if someone is looking for fetching the schema name from Spring JdbcTemplate (instead of plain JDBC), it would be jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().getCatalog() for mySql

Answer (score 4):

- Either use `SHOW DATABASES` to see if
  it is inside,
- Check the INFORMATION_SCHEMA,
- or just do `USE DATABASE;` and catch
  the error.

Answer (score 3):

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet schemas = meta.getSchemas();
while (schemas.next()) {
  String tableSchema = schemas.getString(1);    // "TABLE_SCHEM"
  String tableCatalog = schemas.getString(2); //"TABLE_CATALOG"
  System.out.println("tableSchema "+tableSchema);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = con.getMetaData();
ResultSet ctlgs = dbmd.getCatalogs();
while(ctlgs.next())
{
System.out.println("ctlgs  =  "+ctlgs.getString(1));
}
```