# how to check for database schema existence in MYSQL using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get list of Databases “Schema” names of MySql using java JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679259/how-to-get-list-of-databases-schema-names-of-mysql-using-java-jdbc)

how to check for database schema existence in MYSQL using JDBC ?