# JDBC/Java - How to check if a table and also a column exist in a database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using MySql, jdbc and java for my code. I want the code to check if:

1- A table exists in a particular database.
2- A column exists in a particular table of a particular database.

Can you tell me how to do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679259/how-to-get-list-of-databases-schema-names-of-mysql-using-java-jdbc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A correct way is to use JDBC MetaData

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
DatabaseMetaData metadata = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet resultSet;
resultSet = metadata.getTables(null, null, "tablename", null);
if(resultSet.next())
    // Table exists

resultSet = metadata.getColumns(null, null, "tablename", "columnName");
if(resultSet.next())
    // Column exists
```

To debug your code it might be a good idea to try to fetch all table names first and print them out like this:

```
resultSet = metadata.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while(resultSet.next())
    System.out.println(resultSet.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
```

NB! If no tables are listed, you are using an older version of MySQL JDBC driver with the following bug http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20913 you should either upgrade or use database name as the first argument to getTables

Comment: Then you are using wrong names. Just print out everything you get from the resultSet. Updated example to show how.

Comment: The debugging part of your answer will not work. It needs to be corrected. Put the name of the database that you want to search the table in as 1st parameter. ie, resultSet = metadata.getTables(TheDataBaseNameGoesHere, null, "%", null);

Comment: @anttix- Thanks ! Btw, how did you find that link ? Apparently, its not a bug.

Comment: It is a bug because JDBC spec says that if catalog is set to null, the driver must list tables in all catalogs. Thanx for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'db_name' 
AND table_name = 'table_name';
```

and if it exists then look for the column:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Connection.getMetaData()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getMetaData%28%29), and use the returned object to get the catalogs, schemas, tables and columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
 DatabaseMetaData metadata = connection.getMetaData();
 ResultSet resultSet;
 resultSet = metadata.getTables(null, null, "tablename", null);
 if(resultSet!=null){
   // next() checks if the next table exists ...
      System.out.println("Table exists");
 }
```