# JDBC is not executing SHOW DATABASES command

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

i want to get a list of databases stored in mysql and put in java table using command "show databases" via a resultset. but its not working.

```
DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)dbTbl.getModel();
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost/:3306","root","password");
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("show databases;");
    while(rs.next())
   {
    String db=rs.getString(1);
    model.addRow(new Object[] {db});
   }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    con.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"nahi chalda");
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting? Also ; isnt necessary inside executeQuery

Answer (score 6):

That's not the best way to get a list of Databases in JDBC. Here's the way it's done - using MetaData

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/:3306","root","password");
DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
ResultSet resultSet = meta.getCatalogs();
while (resultSet.next()) {
   String db = resultSet.getString("TABLE_CAT");
   model.addRow(new Object[] {db});
}
resultSet.close();
con.close();
```

See also: [how to get list of Databases "Schema" names of MySql using java JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679259/how-to-get-list-of-databases-schema-names-of-mysql-using-java-jdbc)

Answer (score -1):

I just forgot to add colon after "jdbc:mysql
Correct code is:

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/:3306","root","password");
```

It works ,......... !!!