# how the command 'use database-name' is using java code

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I would like to make o program that would store data from excel files in databases. I have plenty of databases so in my program i have to choose in which one I will store the data.
I have made the code to be able to connect mysql with my program and to show the available databases. What I would like to do now is to say in which database i would store the data. 
To be more specific I would like the user first of all to see tha available databases in his client and afterwards he would have the chance to say in which database the data would be stored.
Could anyone help me how I would do this?

The code to see all the available databases is the below:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", "root", "root");
        DatabaseMetaData meta = (DatabaseMetaData) con.getMetaData();
        ResultSet res = meta.getCatalogs();
        System.out.println("List of the databases: ");
        while (res.next()){
            System.out.println (" " +res.getString(1));
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: your question is bit unclear. database means the schema or the table?

Comment: You can set database in this line (_after user selected one_) - `Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SelectedDatabase", "root", "root");`

Comment: How i would give the user the ability to choose?What i have to write that would be shown in client so that the user would type the one he want?

Answer (score 0):

I hope [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679259/how-to-get-list-of-databases-schema-names-of-mysql-using-java-jdbc) should help you . You can get all the data from the connection object

Comment: @efoikonom, if this answer helps you out, mark it as right answer

Answer (score 0):

First do a create a simple connection

`Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", "root", "root");`

Look for an example [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database)

see how he uses `ResultSet` Class to access the result.

Now,

retrieve information from `information_schema.SCHEMATA` so you can query like

`SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S;`

to get all the schemas

Next after [getting choice from user(maybe from console)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-input-from-console-java/) you can set database according to uservalue using [Connection#setCatalog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setCatalog%28java.lang.String%29)

If you want table information use this query

`SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLES T;`

It would list all the tables in all schemas

Comment: Could you help me with code because i didn't understand you a lot?