# JDBC MySQl don't show result sets

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In my code, My finally output, is not like in MySQl console output:

```
public class d3 {

Connection con;
String dbName = "mydb";
String dbUsername = "root";
String dbPassword = "2323";
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";

public d3() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Find database successfuly");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to find and load driver");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public void connectToDB() {
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword);
        System.out.println("Connect to database succesfully");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Can not connect to database");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public void excuteSQL() {
    String sqlString1 = "use mydb";
    String sqlString2 = "show tables";
    String result;
    try {
        Statement st1 = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet result1 = st1.executeQuery(sqlString1);
         while(result1.next()){
         result = result1.getString(dbName);
         System.out.println(result1);
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println("Can not excute sql statement");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    d3 ddd = new d3();
    ddd.connectToDB();
    ddd.excuteSQL();
}
}
```

My output:

```
Find database successfuly
Connect to database succesfully
Result set representing update count of 0
```

But, I want to be like this:

```
Find database successfuly
Connect to database succesfully
Database changed      // this is shown in console
```

I am going step by step and comparing outputs from mysql console and my IDE console,
For example, I want to see "Database changed" message after execute "use mydb" statement.

Comment: Are you sure "show tables" is a statement that your JDBC driver understands and returns a resultset for?

Comment: Try using [`execute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)). It returns `boolean true` if the querie get executed. I think `"use mydb"` never returns `ResultSet`.

Comment: @DaveHowes How sure for it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get list of Databases "Schema" names of MySql using java JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679259/how-to-get-list-of-databases-schema-names-of-mysql-using-java-jdbc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing `use mydb`, which doesn't produce a result set (it isn't a query). Also, you should not use this command to set your current database, JDBC requires you to use the JDBC methods. See the javadoc of java.sql.Connection:

> **Note**: When configuring a `Connection`, JDBC applications should use the appropriate `Connection` method such as `setAutoCommit` or `setTransactionIsolation`. Applications should not invoke SQL commands directly to change the connection's configuration when there is a JDBC method available.

The equivalent of `USE mydb` is [`Connection.setCatalog("mydb")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setCatalog%28java.lang.String%29), calling this method makes sure the driver is in a consistent state. If you look at the actual implementation in MySQL Connector/J this method eventually calls `USE mydb`, but it also does additional checks and changes to the state of the `Connection` object.

When you already know which database you want to use, just include it directly into the connection URL:

```
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";
```

Similarly, you shouldn't use `SHOW TABLES` to get information on tables, use [`DatabaseMetaData.getTables()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) instead. Using JDBC methods over MySQL specific commands makes your program more portable.

Comment: Thanks so much, Is there a place that i see all of this equivalent statements between mysql console and JDBC methods?

Comment: @Sajjad- I don't know, I normally don't use MySQL ;)

Comment: Is the Connection.setCatalog("mydb") method return any thing?

Answer (score 1):

you should do:

```
while (resultset.next()) {

System.out.println(resultset.getString("somevariable")
}
```

Some variable just represents what you are looking for in your table.
Also, I'm not sure that "use mydb" works with JDBC.
If you use a command string like

```
("SELECT NAME FROM TABLE")
```

then you would have to use something like

```
System.out.println(resultset.getString("NAME")
```

to look for stuff in the table column named "NAME".

Comment: Can you explain about somevariable

Comment: Refer to the possible duplicate link. This won't do it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza are you sure that that is what he means?

Comment: @karki64 yes, OP wants/needs the tables in a database (schema). That link provide that info based on the metadata of the connection.