# run a mysql command from java

Tags: java, mysql

hi I have a JAVA project in which I want to display the MySQL databases.
i write this code:

```
try {
     String []command={"mysql -u root -pmanager","show databases"};
        Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysql -u root -pmanager");
        Process p1= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("show databases");
        if (p.waitFor()==0){System.out.println("backup done...");}
        else{System.out.println("!!!");}
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but it give me this error:

```
Cannot run program "show": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

what it should be do?
thanks...

Comment: You aren't executing `show` within `mysql`, you're executing it as a new command line command.

Comment: I'm unsure, but try getting the outpustream from the mysql process and writing to that.

Comment: See [answers of this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679259/how-to-get-list-of-databases-schema-names-of-mysql-using-java-jdbc) post, it shows how to get mysql database names using java.

Comment: `show databases` can be run through JDBC as well. Why do you want to run that as an external process?

Comment: add fully qualified path for the mysql.exe for process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to pass String object in exec method like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(  new String [] {"mysql", "-u", "root", "-pmanager", "-e", "show databases"} )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what is 'mysql' to command prompt...
example - C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql