# How to create connection with root of mysql for access all database ?

Tags: java, mysql, database, user-interface, jframe

I want to create a connection with root of mysql for access all databases.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside that using the `root` account for something different than administrative purposes might be a bad idea ... well, still, you cannot connect to "all databases", at least not at once. What you can do is:

- create a connection to one of the existing databases. (most likely use `mysql` for a start, as you can be sure this one exists)
- if you need to point the connection to a different database, use the `connection.setCatalog(String)` method of the `java.sql.Connection` class to switch to a different database.

If you want to know which databases exist, see this question: [how to get list of Databases "Schema" names of MySql using java JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679259/how-to-get-list-of-databases-schema-names-of-mysql-using-java-jdbc)

Comment: How can I fetch all database name ?

Comment: Oops, I missed that , sorry and Thanks